# Building a dom-subtree in the background

Tags: javascript, dom, worker

Building a large and complex dom-subtree in javascript is quite slow and expensive. Is it possible to build such a tree in the background, maybe using a `worker` and only append it to the main dom-tree when the building is completed?

I know that workers do not have access to the dom and xml libraries, but maybe there is a common workaround to lazy load subtrees when they are needed.

```
var c = document.createDocumentFragment();

// takes several seconds to execute, should not block main thread.
// may be inside a worker...
buildLargeAndComplexSubtree(c);

// append subtree to the main tree in the main thread.
document.body.appendChild(c);
```

Comment: What about wrapping it into async func?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using setTimeout will help taking it out of the main thread and improve performance:

```js
setTimeout(function () {
    var c = document.createDocumentFragment();
    // takes several seconds to execute, should not block main thread.
    // may be inside a worker...
    buildLargeAndComplexSubtree(c);
    // append subtree to the main tree in the main thread.
    document.body.appendChild(c);
}, 0);
```

Comment: The timeout still runs on the main thread, just "later" (which is probably after the method returns to dom).